# Facebook FQL to get all posts made by friends and using App

Tags: ios, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get a list of all posts made by my friends using a certain `app_id`. I tried a multi-query FQL like this:

```
{
"friends":"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = MY_USER_ID",
"posts":"SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #friends) AND app_id= APP_ID"
}
```

This FQL doesn't return anything, although one of my friends made a post using the app (I verified that the first FQL, `#friends`, does return the friend who made the post). I tried it with a test account that has only one friend and it worked.

Is there any reason this might not work with users with lots of friends ?

Answer (score 2):

What about combining them into 1 nested query -

```
SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND app_id = APP_ID
```

If that doesn't work as well, it could be related to how your friend has configured the privacy settings for their posts/activity that can be used by their friends' apps.

Comment: Thanks but that does not work either. Also I confirmed the privacy setting for my app are correct. I tried the following FQL: SELECT uid, status_id, message,source,time FROM status WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND source = APP_ID LIMIT 1000 . This query only returns my friends posts by the app that are relatively new , older posts are not returned even if I utilize the time field. Interestingly, executing the same query with uid=m(), i.e to get my posts, returns data correctly even if they are old.